# Creating A Bar Chart using ggplot with a Manual dataframe one row 5 columns

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, data-visualization, data-wrangling

[image]

This is my data frame. I could not find a way to construct a bar plot using ggplot with the column names and x as the values indicated.

Comment: bk2nt, welcome to SO! Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments it is bad practice to post images of codes/data/errors. I copied only the first two entries of your data frame. 
In general for ggplot (and the entire tidyverse) observations should be in rows not columns. You therefore first need to transform your data and then plotting is fairly straight forward.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- data.frame(white = 48.8, asian = 40)
df1 %>% 
  t() %>% # convert columns to rows
  as.data.frame() %>% # need to change it to a data frame as t() converts it to a matrix
  rownames_to_column("id") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = id, y = V1)) +
  geom_col()
```

Resulting in:

[image]